# Installing a version of Django REST framework that is compatible with Django 4+

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am in the process of upgrading from Django 3.2 to Django 4.0.

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

And the error seems to stem from this import:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

in rest_auth/registration/serializers.py

I'm currently running Django 4.0.10 with djangorestframework 3.13.0, and I'm a bit confused because according to Django REST framework's [release notes](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#313x-series) v3.13.0 should support Django 4.0 (I also tried v3.14.0, same results).

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 304, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/rdhq_django/cal_submit/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from races.serializers import RaceSerializer
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/rdhq_django/races/serializers.py", line 9, in <module>
    from users.serializers import UserField, SerializerImageMixin
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/rdhq_django/users/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer as _RegisterSerializer
  File "/Users/Panos/rdhq_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
ImportError: cannot import name 'ugettext_lazy' from 'django.utils.translation'
```

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace? I fear this is not coming from DRF. Maybe `django-rest-auth`?

Comment: Hi Marco - I edited my post to add a full traceback of the error. By the way, we run on django-rest-auth v0.9.5 which seems to be the latest version.

Comment: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth is deprecated and no longer maintained. The error comes from [this line](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/cdd04aa9be7ad3da6b417380ee14b3ff4d5459ba/rest_auth/registration/serializers.py#L2) You should use another library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Marco mentioned, `django-rest-auth` has been deprecated. I'm switching to a fork, [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth) which seems to be maintained.